# How to match a word, print the line and the next line, over and over in a file

Tags: python

Registrar looking to parse text file that includes data from many students.

Input file: text file of many students data (each students file is formatted the same)

I have been successful in finding a "pattern" and printing it to file which is 75% of what I need.  There is one case where I need to print the next line after the match has been found and the match line has been printed.
That's where I'm lost.  [iterable, iterator, generator...all greek to me]

Example of text:

```
Student............: StudentA
Program............: BA Adol Biology Education (ED.ADOL.BIO.BA)

C) 3: Lab Science Course
Complete 1 Lab Science course
CHM-111 General Chemistry I *4..... FA2018   A         4

I) 4: Adolescent Biology Education Major
Credits: 24
GPA Achieved/Needed: 4.000 / 2.500
Complete all 3 subrequirements:
I) A: Educ Requirements
COMPLETE 2 GROUPS
Credits: 5
GPA Achieved/Needed: none / 3.000
I) Group 1
Student............: StudentB
Program............: BA Adol Eng Education (ED.ADOL.ENG.BA)

C) 3: Lab Science Course
Complete 1 Lab Science course;
CHM-111 General Chemistry I *4..... FA2018   A         4
I) 4: Adolescent English Education Major
Credits: 24
GPA Achieved/Needed: 4.000 / 2.500
Complete all 3 subrequirements:
I) A: Educ Requirements
COMPLETE 2 GROUPS
Credits: 5
GPA Achieved/Needed: none / 3.000
I) Group 1
Student............: StudentC
Program............: BA Adol Chemistry Education (ED.ADOL.CHM.BA)

C) 3: Lab Science Course  
Complete 1 Lab Science course;
CHM-111 General Chemistry I *4..... FA2018   A         4
I) 4: Adolescent Chemistry Education Major
Credits: 24
GPA Achieved/Needed: 4.000 / 2.500
Complete all 3 subrequirements:
I) A: Educ Requirements
COMPLETE 2 GROUPS
Credits: 5
```

Running Python 3.7.1; have tried playing with `__next__()` but have not been successful. From what I've read `print()` moves the pointer to the next line...so I tried doing that, but that doesn't work.

```
outfile = open('result.txt', 'w')
with open('BEVL_EDU.txt','r') as inFile:
f = inFile.read().splitlines()
for line in f:
    if 'Student...' in line:
        outfile.write(line + '\n')
    if '4:' in line:
        outfile.write(line + '\n')
        print(line)                 # --> this is where I tried to move the pointer to next line
        outfile.write(line + '\n')  # --> and then print the "next" line :-)
    if 'GPA Achieved/Needed' in line:
        outfile.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: In which case do you need to "print the next line after the match has been found"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something you should do first to make your code more idiomatic python.  Files can be iterated over directly.  So instead of:

`f = inFile.read().splitlines()`

You should just use:

`for line in inFile:`

Now that we've got your code operating directly on your file, like we do in python, you can get the next line in the file by simply calling `next(inFile)`.  This will advance the file iterator and return the value, and it won't break your `for` loop.

Comment: I made the changes and the code didn't throw an error, but it didn't print the 2nd line.   Here is what the code looks like where I want the line with "4:" written and the line after.      
    if '4:' in line:
            outfile.write(line + '\n')
            next (inFile)
            outfile.write(line + '\n')

Comment: `next(inFile)` advances the iterator and returns the new value.  You need to store it somewhere (`line = next(inFile)`), then writing it will give you the value you expect.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing this: outfile.write(next(inFile, '').strip() + '\n')  not exactly sure what the strip does - but it worked.  I like Python!

Comment: @jbird - Excellent!  Remember to mark an answer as accepted if you've received the help you need.